# How to yank the filename of specific buffer?

Tags: buffers, insert-mode

Is there a (simple) way to yank the filename of specific buffer in insert mode?

For example, in insert mode, `Ctrl+R %` gives the name from current buffer, `Ctrl+R #` gives the alt one, but what about an arbitrary number, for example 1, for buffer 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use the [expression register `=`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#quote%3D) together with the [`bufname()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#bufname%28%29) function.

In Insert mode, you can enter the following sequence: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>, `bufname(1)`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will insert the name of buffer 1 into the current location.

Comment: and/or `"=bufname(1)<CR>p`

Answer (score 2):

if you mean paste by yank then you can use `:h bufname()` function and `=` expression register: `<C-r>=bufname(1)<CR>`.